# I am trying to get data from mongodb to elastic using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to get data from mongodb to elastic using logstash

but i get below errors:

```
Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseError: Java::OrgLogstash::Missing
ConverterException:
```

below is my config file:

```
input{
    jdbc{
        jdbc_driver_library => "D:/mongojdbc1.2.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017/users"
        jdbc_user => ""
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        statement => "db.user_details.find({})"
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => 'http://localhost:9200'
    index => 'person_data'
    document_type => "person_data"
 }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: I think that there is something missing in your exception, you should get the classname that is missing after the  MissingConverterException

Answer (score 0):

This possibly happens because certain data type in Mongo might not be convertible to data type in Elasticsearch. May be you should try to select few columns and then see which one is failing.